# Add values to "let"

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. I have a let x, and I want to add to it more values (parsing from a mongodb request). The problem is that finally I have [object Object] and not the values.

How should I handle this?

```
let x='[{"user": "test","Name": "test"},';
x+='{"user": "test2","Name": "test2"}]';
let self=this;
let url1 = "POST get list from DB";
let jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url1,
    async: false
}, function() {
    console.log( "success" );
})
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(x);
            $(data).each(function(){
                console.log(this);
                x+=this;
            })
        console.log(x);
    });
```

The output:

[output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQCqR.png)

Many thanks.

Comment: You are concatenating object to a string let x. let x is a string. Make it an array.

Comment: `url1` doesn't look like a valid URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let url1 = "POST get list from DB";` is not a valid `URL`

You need to `push` *object* inside *array*

You should follow the way like below

```
let x=[{"user": "test","Name": "test"}];
x.push({"user": "test2","Name": "test2"});

console.log(x);
```

Comment: I know that this is not a valid URL. It's local server so I cannot post it here. i will try your solution. thanks